# Save SQL SELECT COUNT value in integer

Tags: c#, sql, database

I want to get the scheme of a database.
For this purpose, I wrote a select count script that counts all tables in my database which are plm.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE Table_schema like 'plm'
```

The script is saved in string sql2.

Now I have an integer value which shall be filled with the number of counted tables.

```
int schemePLM = 0;

using (var command = new SqlCommand())
            {

                command.CommandText = sql2;

                command.Connection = con.Con;

                con.conOpen();

                schemePLM = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar().toString());

                if (schemePLM > 0)
                {
                    Database.Scheme = "plm";
                }
```

When executing, the value of schemePLM is still 0.

Comment: Does the command.ExecuteScalar().toString() return the right number?

Comment: I would try that command in SSMS to check if it returns something. You are searching for tables in the schema PLM. Are you sure you have that schema in the current database connection?

Comment: Yes, the database scheme is plm. In SSMS it returns 383.

Comment: And the database connection is right? Does your connectionstring contains the DATADIRECTORY shortcut?

Comment: Everything is right.

Comment: The main issue is to get the counted number and save it into a int in c#

Comment: Pre conversion does the ExecuteScalar() return 383?

Comment: Side points: Don't use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` it is for compatibility only, use `sys.tables` and `sys.schemas` instead. You must dispose your connection object, do *not* cache it. `Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar().toString())` is just silly, you can just cast it direct to `int` like this `(int)command.ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE Table_schema like '%plm%'
```

When using `LIKE` you need to wrap what you are looking for with %.

If you are searching for this exact word (plm) you use =.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE Table_schema = 'plm'
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But it doese work with all of the variantes.